# Build GBM classification model with customer post-stratification weights

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, r-caret, gbm

I am attempting to produce a classification model based on the work of qualitative survey data. About 10K of our customers were researched and as a result a segmentation model was built and subsequently each customer categorised into 1 of 8 customer segments. The challenge is to now classify the TOTAL customer base into those segments. As only certain customers responded the researcher used overall demographics to apply  post-stratification weights (or frequency weights).

My task is to now use our customer data as explanatory variables on this 10K in order to build a classification model for the whole base.

In order to handle the customer weights I simply duplicated each customer record by each respective frequency weight and the data set exploded to about 72K. I then split this data into train and test and used the R caret package to train a GBM and using the final chosen model classified my hold-out test set.

I was getting 82% accuracy and thought the results were too good to be true. After thinking about it I think the issue is that the model is inadvertently seeing records in train that are exactly the same in test (some records might be exactly duplicated up to 10 times).

I know that the GLM model function allows you to use the weight parameter to refer to a vector of weights but my question is how to utilise other machine learning algorithms, such as GBM or Random Forests, in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use case weights with `gbm` and `train`. In general, the list of models in `caret` that can use case weights is [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#Accepts_Case_Weights).

Comment: Thank you- I can't believe I missed it! I am a big fan of CARET and the Applied Predictive Modelling book (it is in prime position on my bookshelf). In fact at work I would say that I mention the package and book at least 3 times a day to my colleagues!